# Java codes not being executed (run) on my macbook's VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Right now, I haven't even started actually coding Java. I have just installed java on my Macbook and set up my Visual Studio Code. I wanted to sample a program out to see how it will be run there. However, it is not running at all no matter how much I click on the run button or press f5. I would appreciate the help :( Thank you[A screenshot of the program page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSbzr.png)

Comment: You haven't shown any error messages or provided any information on your configuration so we can't really help. Note that VS does not natively support java, you need to rely on [plugins/extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) to make it work. A better solution would be to use an IDE developed for java, like [Netbeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/)

Comment: @sorifiend In the past, a terminal that says like output, debug, or stuff appeared at the bottom of the screen and would at least show error or such when I run; however now it just stays in that screen I shared in the screenshot.
I have installed the java extension pack wholly provided my Microsoft.

Comment: It looks like your terminal/console has been hidden, your first step is to show it so you can see the output and the associated errors. It has been a long time since I used VS Code so am not familiar with how it's done in the current versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the left bottom corner and click
[image]
Then you can see the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Wimukthi Rajapaksha, you can try it first.Besides, we can also use the Ctrl+` keyboard shortcut or the View > Terminal menu command.
If none of these steps work, I would like to know if the result will appear in the terminal after the code is run？

Comment: As you're basically replying to someone's answer, I think this is a candidate for comment rather than an answer. If commenting is not possible due to some reason then you shouldn't post answers as such.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).